# Consulta como dirigirse de un Fragment a al Fragment b antes de grabar

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les cuento que ya tengo listo para grabar los datos de los fragment que son en total cinco, ahora estoy haciendo lo siguiente que al momento de grabar compro los datos que son obligatorios y estos que den un mensaje al usuario que falta y se dirija al fragment que corresponde, es to es lo que tengo hecho hasta el momento:

```
private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.segundo, fragmentAsegurado,"asegurado").commit();
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("traspaso", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            String valor = bundle.getString("campo1");
            String valor1 = bundle.getString("campo2");
            String valor2 = bundle.getString("campo3");
            String valor3 = bundle.getString("campo4");
            String valor4 = bundle.getString("campo5");
            String valor5 = bundle.getString("campo6");
            String valor6 = bundle.getString("campo7");
            String valor7 = bundle.getString("campo8");
            String valor8 = bundle.getString("campo9");
            String valor9 = bundle.getString("campo10");
            String valor10 = bundle.getString("campo11");
            a.setText(valor);
            b.setText(valor1);
            c.setText(valor2);
            d.setText(valor3);
            e.setText(valor4);
            f.setText(valor5);
            g.setText(valor6);
            h.setText(valor7);
            i.setText(valor8);
            j.setText(valor9);
            k.setText(valor10);
        }
    });
```

estos son los que corresponden al fragment denominado asegurado.
Ahora este es el código que utilizo para el traspaso:

```
    aseg = a.getText().toString();
    rut = b.getText().toString();
    conductor = f.getText().toString();
    rut1 = g.getText().toString();
    licencia = j.getText().toString();
    control = k.getText().toString();
```

ahora les presento el código para un if como ejemplo:

```
else if (licencia.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo la Licencia del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (fragmentAsegurado != null) {
            fragmentAsegurado.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtlicencia).requestFocus();
            //fragmentAsegurado.txtlicencia.requestFocus();
        }
        return;
    }
```

funciona bien hasta aquí voy bien, pero al momento de que se cumpla que el fragmentAsegurado es distinto de vacío entra como debe ser y posteriormente debe irse al fragment del asegurado e irse al edittext denominado txtlicencia, pero no lo hace y realiza un loop y posteriormente me bota, en que estoy fallando, ojala que me puedan ayudar y asesorar, desde ya muchas gracias.

De acuerdo a lo solicitado el logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos.ejecutarServicio(datos.java:472)
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos.access$500(datos.java:35)
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos$5.onClick(datos.java:237)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "me bota"? Si existe un error en el LogCat debes agregarlo a tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: @Jorgesys muy buenas, te comento me refiero a que cae y vuelve a foja cero, y te puse lo solicitado el logcat, ojala que me puedas ayudar, ya que llevo más de una semana y nadie me ha querido ayudar

Comment: Que clase es donde tienes "else if (licencia.isEmpty()){", te sugiero agregar toda esa clase

Comment: @Jorgesys muy buenas, te comento que no es una clase, si te das cuenta es el traspaso de los datos que se realiza del fragment  del asegurado, al fragment denominado datos, y en el cual se comprara si esta vacio debe dirigirse al fragment asegurado y al edittext llamado txtlicencia, mis disculpas por no contestar antes.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que probablemente estés diseñando incorrectamente tu app, ya que entiendo cuál es el problema, **estás tratando de obtener la referencia de una vista dentro de un `fragment` al únicamente instanciarlo**:

```
fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
...
if (fragmentAsegurado != null) {
    fragmentAsegurado.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtlicencia).requestFocus();
    //fragmentAsegurado.txtlicencia.requestFocus();
}
```

Lo anterior es incorrecto.

---

Para obtener la referencia de una vista que existe en tu `Fragment` mediante `.findViewById` , debes cargar el `Fragment` puedes obtener la referencia de la vista:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(R.id.txtlicencia).requestFocus();

}
```

Comment: muy buenas, te comento que cuando encuentre que la variable licencia es vacia, debe dirijirse al fragment del asegurado, es o es lo que quiero, y lo que me recomiendas como lo implemento, dentro del fragment datos o dentro del fragment asegurado, al parecer nadie me entiende lo que pretendo hacer

Comment: al parecer en los fragment de android studio no se puede hacer, que cuando encuentre un If que es vacio como licencia y se dirija al fragment asegurado no se puede hacer, como en los otros que tambien son tabuladores como: en netbeanas, en visual studio (asp.net), en visual studio code, pero aquí puros problemas, al parecer mejor hacerlo en un activity e ingresar las 50 cajas de edittext para que el usuario valla a ingresar un listado grande, lo digo por que llevo máas de una semana y no he podido hacerlo